# Empty preimage of an intersection implies empty intersection of the preimages

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Assume $f:A\to A'$ is a function, $B\subset A'$, $C\subset A'$, and $f^{-1}(B\cap C)=\emptyset$

How can we see that $f^{-1}(B)\cap f^{-1}(C)=\emptyset$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$x\in f^{-1}(B)\cap f^{-1}(C)\implies f(x)\in B\cap C \implies x\in f^{-1}(B\cap C).$$

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $f^{-1}(B\cap C)=f^{-1}(B)\cap f^{-1}(C)$ holds in general.

Comment: How can we see the reverse inclusion?

Comment: $$x\in f^{-1}(B\cap C) \implies f(x)\in B\cap C \implies f(x) \in B,f(x) \in C \implies x\in f^{-1}(B) \text{ and } x \in f^{-1}(C) \implies x\in f^{-1}(B)\cap f^{-1}(C).$$

Comment: Ah, but you claim the **reverse** is also true. How can we see the **reverse** inclusion?

Comment: Other people have already shown that, for example the answer by mfl.

Answer (score 1):

If $x\in f^{-1}(B)\cap f^{-1}(C)$ then by definiton $f(x)\in B$ and $f(x)\in C$. Hence $f(x)\in B\cap C$ and $x\in f^{-1}(B\cap C)$.

This is enough to get your conclusion: if $f^{-1}(B\cap C)=\emptyset$ then $f^{-1}(B)\cap f^{-1}(C)=\emptyset$.

However, we can also prove the reverse direction: If $x\in f^{-1}(B\cap C)$ then by definition $f(x)\in B\cap C$, hence $f(x)\in B$ and $f(x)\in C$, hence $x\in f^{-1}(B)$ and $x\in f^{-1}(C)$, so we get $x\in f^{-1}(B)\cap f^{-1}(C)$.

We have now proven $f^{-1}(B)\cap f^{-1}(C)\subseteq f^{-1}(B\cap C)\subseteq f^{-1}(B)\cap f^{-1}(C)$, so $$f^{-1}(B)\cap f^{-1}(C)= f^{-1}(B\cap C)$$

Answer (score 0):

$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\calcop}[2]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \text{"#2"} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
$Here is essentially the same pair of proofs that others showed, but with both directions at the same time.  (This duplicates parts of the earlier answers, but I did not see an earlier answer I dared to update.)

I'll write $\;f[X]\;$ instead of $\;f(X)\;$ for clarity, to distinguish it from $\;f(x)\;$.

Note that the basic property (or the definition) of $\;\cdot^{-1}[\cdot]\;$ is
$$
\tag{0} x \in f^{-1}[Y] \;\iff\; f(x) \in Y
$$

Our strategy is to start with the most complex part, apply the definitions, simplify, and see where that leads us.

---

For every $\;x\;$, we calculate
$$\calc
x \in f^{-1}[B] \cap f^{-1}[C]
\calcop{\iff}{definition of $\;\cap\;$}
x \in f^{-1}[B] \;\land\; x \in f^{-1}[C]
\calcop{\iff}{definition $(0)$, twice}
f(x) \in B \;\land\; f(x) \in C
\calcop{\iff}{definition of $\;\cap\;$ -- working towards our goal}
f(x) \in B \cap C
\calcop{\iff}{definition $(0)$}
x \in f^{-1}[B \cap C]
\endcalc$$

Therefore (by set extensionality) $\;f^{-1}[B] \cap f^{-1}[C] \;=\; f^{-1}[B \cap C]\;$.  And therefore one is $\;\emptyset\;$ iff the other is.